# JavaScript. Find the sum of a certain parameter in an array to produce a popup if that sum == 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sum, chart.js

```
$(function () {
    $('.performance-container').each(function () {
        var container = $(this);
        var updateForm = $('.performance-form', container);
        var chartCanvas = $('.performance-canvas', container)[0];
        var chart = null;
        $('.performance-datetimepicker', container).datetimepicker({
            widgetPositioning: {
                horizontal: "auto",
                vertical: "bottom"
            }
        });
        updateForm.submit(function (event) {
            window.classiDocs.showLoadingOverlay(container.parents('.x_panel'));
            $.post(window.classiDocs.reporting.routes.classificationPerformance, updateForm.serialize(),
                function (data) {
                    var chartData = data.Items.map(function (historyItem) {
                        return { x: historyItem.Timestamp, y: historyItem.Value };                    
                    });
                    if (!chart) {
                        initialize(chartData);
                    } else {
                        chart.data.datasets[0].data = chartData;
                        chart.update();
                    }
                })
                .always(function () {
                    window.classiDocs.hideLoadingOverlay(container.parents('.x_panel'));
                });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        

        $(updateForm).submit();
        function initialize(data) {
            console.log(data);
            chart = new Chart(chartCanvas.getContext("2d"), {
                type: "line",
                data: {
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.31)",
                            borderColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                            pointBorderColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                            pointBorderWidth: 1,
                            lineTension: 0,
                            tension: 0,
                            data: data
                        }
                    ]
                },
                options: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false
                    },
                    tooltips: {
                        callbacks: {
                            title: function (items) {
                                return new Date(items[0].xLabel).toLocaleString();
                            },
                            label: function (item) {
                                return item.y.toLocaleString();
                            },
                            footer: function () {
                                return null;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [
                            {
                                type: "time",
                                scaleLabel: {
                                    display: true,
                                    labelString: 'Time Span',
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontColor: "#555555"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        yAxes: [
                            {
                                scaleLabel: {
                                    display: true,
                                    labelString: 'Number Of Classifications',
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    fontColor: "#555555"
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                    beginAtZero: true
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Hi all.  I am still new to development so excuse any incorrect use of terminology. My goal here is to add a popup if the sum of the values on the y axis are equal to 0. The console.log(data); in this code returns two object arrays. The data in these arrays are returned in the console as follows:

```
0: {x: "2020-10-01T00:00:00", y: 0}
1: {x: "2020-10-01T00:30:00", y: 0}
2: {x: "2020-10-01T01:00:00", y: 0}
3: {x: "2020-10-01T01:30:00", y: 0}
4: {x: "2020-10-01T02:00:00", y: 0}
5: {x: "2020-10-01T02:30:00", y: 0}
```

This chart is being used dynamically so this one script produces two graphs.  How could i loop through both arrays and find the sum of "y" for each? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), here is the complete code

```
if (data.reduce((a, v) => a + v.y, 0) === 0) {
  alert('The sum of data.y is zero!');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Yusut.  I will try this as soon as I am done with another task and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Worked perfectly @Yusut.  Thanks!